# Macbook backlight not working on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, backlight

I am not able to set my screen brightness on my macbook running arch linux. The macbook is a 15 inch 2012 model and I am using Arch Linux 4.11.5-1.
I have read up on arch linux wiki "[backlight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight)", "[Mac](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac)", and different other forums and posts but I cant quite get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this issue in the future, here is how I solved it. I just used `gmux_backlight +50000` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Desktop environment? In the past I had many problems regarding screen brightness on LXDE desktop environment and changing to XFCE fixed all my problems.

Comment: I am using Openbox

Comment: Overall the LXDE desktop environment is itself built around Openbox. I would try a more modern DE. Try for example XFCE, MATE or GNOME and see will it work.